# What exactly is the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Sorry for such question, But I don't know what exactly is the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$? Induced by $\iota:\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R^n$ or $\varphi :\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb R\times \Bbb S^{n-1}$ or something else?

**Update:** It seems that my problem is misunderstanding the "induced" maybe. This is my thought: because $x,y\in \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ are also in $\Bbb R^n$ so $d(x,y)=d_{can}(x,y)$. but this do not work for $x=(1,0,0...,0)$ and $y=(−1,0,0...,0)$!!

Comment: It is an open set in $\Bbb R^n$ with the Euclidean metric, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459224/prove-that-mathbbrn-without-the-origin-is-an-open-set-with-the-euclidean-m).

Comment: It's the one induced by $\iota$. Did you mean $\varphi$ as $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\} \to \Bbb R_{>0}\times \Bbb S^{n-1}$? By the way, I guess they generate equivalent metrics.

Comment: Depending on the context, perhaps what is meant is simply the restriction to $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ of the usual Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$. This is what I would have thought of first, if the answer was not necessarily supposed to have something to do with tag riemannian-geometry

Comment: @Mirko, My question is exactly what you explained. if it is just a restriction, so what is the $d(x,y)$ for antipodal points $x,y$ i.e. $x=-y$?

Comment: it is the same as what it was before $0$ was removed. $d(-1,1)=2$.What do you denote by $d_{can}$ in your post? $d$ is a metric, formally a function from $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ into $\Bbb R$, and then we restrict the domain of this function to $(\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n)\setminus((\Bbb R^n\times\{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times\Bbb R^n))$

Comment: Are you sure? but I think $d(x,y):= \inf\{ \text{curves from $x$ to $y$ on $M$}\}$ that that line is not on $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: well, I am not sure, it depends on the context. If the context was not necessarily tag riemanian-geometry, then I would have been pretty sure. But even if you take $\inf$, don't you get again that $d(-1,1)=2$?

Comment: No. Then we must have two minimizing curve in $\Bbb R^n$ that is impossible.

Comment: Why nobody answer to my question precisely?

Answer (score 1):

[By definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space#Euclidean_structure), a Euclidean space is an affine space, often confused with a vector space. Since $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is no longer an affine space, there is no standard definition of the Euclidean distance on it.